# How can I export all of my MMS pictures before changing phones?

Tags: backup, sms, mms, google-messages

I am currently using the stock Google Messenger app which came installed on my LG V20. I'm getting a new phone and backing up my data beforehand. It turns out that Messenger doesn't have any method to export all the attached MMS pictures. I can long-press *each picture* and save it individually, but then I have to scroll through hundreds of threads and tens of thousands of messages! I'm guessing I have ~1000 pictures buried in there...

Now I'm pursuing other apps. Perhaps I could import my MMS messages into a new app which would then allow me to save them?

There used to be something called "Save MMS", but it's no longer available. [SMS Backup and Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) supposedly backs up pictures in XML format, but I haven't found a way to extract them into files. It looks like [Textra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra) will auto-save incoming MMS pictures into a directory, but not with old pictures found during an import...

My goal is to save these images as files and move them to a computer. I don't want them on the new phone.

Does anyone have any clever ideas?

Comment: try [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31155) it claims to handle MMS (not tested by me)

Comment: I use SMS backup and restore app but not MMS. However, this link from that app help page (faq) indicates that MMS can be restored. Give it a try by selecting a date range to copy and restore https://synctech.com.au/faqs/pixel-mms-missing/// xml format is for call logs and SMS text not MMS media