# Trying to back up my phone data using ADB but having a lot of problems

Tags: adb, backup, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I want to back up the data on my Samsung Galaxy 5 (particularly SMSs and Memo text documents). I'm trying to do it with Android Debug Bridge. I followed some online "help" pages but ran into all kinds of problems. I'm using Ubuntu, version: 20.04.2 LTS. Can somebody please walk me through this supposedly simple and straightforward process? I tried using another app, SmartSwitch, but couldn't get it to install on my PC.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231568 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172765